# php: How to get n length words from sentence?

Tags: php, regex

Suppose

```
$length = 4;
$sentence = 'There are so many words in a para';
```

As given length is 4, so output will be:-

```
$output = array('many', 'para');
```

What will be the **regex to get expected output**?

Comment: `/some conditions here/`. The rest is up to you.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this regex:

```
\b\w{4}\b
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aS6jD2/1)

**Code:**

```
$re = '/\b\w{4}\b/'; 
$str = "There are so many words in a para"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $m);

print_r($m[0]);
```

Comment: use @anubhava regex with preg_match_all function

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, and to show a non-regexp way of achieving the same objective:

```
$length = 4;
$sentence = 'There are so many words in a para';

$i = 0;
$words = array_filter(
    str_word_count($sentence, 1),
    function ($word) use(&$i, $length) {
        return ++$i % $length == 0;
    }
);
var_dump($words);
```